# Compare two IQueryable instances

Tags: c#, linq

I have two `IQueryable` instances - `objIQuerableA` and `objIQueryableB` and I want to obtain only elements that are present in `objIQuerableA` and not in `objIQuerableB`.

One way is to use a foreach loop but I wonder if there is a better method.

Answer (score 8):

Simple and straight forward.

```
var result = objIQuerableA.Except(objIQuerableB);
```

Answer (score 3):

The title actually says compare two IQueryables.  If you wanted to actually do a compare to determine if both IQueryable contain the same results in a single query....

```
var aExceptB = objIQuerableA.Except(objIQuerableB);
var bExceptA = objIQuerableB.Except(objIQuerableA);
var symmetricDiff = aExceptB.Union(bExceptA);
bool areDifferent = symmetricDiff.Any();
```